# Append select with missing month and year values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I have SELECT:

```
SELECT month, year, ROUND(AVG(q_overall) OVER (rows BETWEEN 10000 preceding and current row),2) as avg 
FROM (
  SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM date) as month, EXTRACT(Year FROM date) as year, ROUND(AVG(q_overall),1) as q_overall 
  FROM fb_parsed 
  WHERE business_id = 1
  GROUP BY year, month
  ORDER BY year, month) a
```

output:

```
 month  year  avg       
 ----------------- 
 12     2012  5 
 1      2013  4.5
 2      2013  4.1
 4      2013  4.8
 5      2013  4.7
```

And I have to append this table with missing values (in this example with 3-rd month in 2013 year). The avg must be same as in previous row, that means I need to append this table with:

```
 3      2013  4.1
```

Can I do this with SELF JOINS and generate_series, or with some UNION select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your select.  It doesn't need a subquery:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM date) as month,
       EXTRACT(Year FROM date) as year,
       ROUND(AVG(q_overall), 1) as q_overall,
       ROUND(AVG(AVG(q_overall)) OVER (rows BETWEEN 10000 preceding and current row), 2)
FROM fb_parsed 
WHERE business_id = 1
GROUP BY year, month;
```

The windows function needs an `order by`.  I assume you really intend:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM date) as month,
       EXTRACT(Year FROM date) as year,
       ROUND(AVG(q_overall), 1) as q_overall,
       ROUND(AVG(AVG(q_overall)) OVER (ORDER BY year, month)), 2)
FROM fb_parsed 
WHERE business_id = 1
GROUP BY year, month;
```

Then, to fill in the values you can use `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM ym.date) as month,
       EXTRACT(Year FROM ym.date) as year,
       ROUND(AVG(AVG(q_overall)) OVER (ORDER BY year, month)), 2)
FROM (SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(date)),
                             date_trunc('month', max(date)),
                             interval '1 month') as date
      FROM fb_parsed 
     ) ym LEFT JOIN
     fb_parsed p
     ON EXTRACT(year FROM ym.date) = EXTRACT(year FROM p.date) AND
        EXTRACT(month FROM ym.date) = EXTRACT(month FROM p.date) AND
        p.business_id = 1
GROUP BY year, month;
```

I think this will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped me Gordon. Postgresql throwed me some errors in your last query, because pg dont know year and month in ORDER BY on 3-rd row and fb_parsed table has many other data, so I have to append a little WHERE clausules, but now it works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this with SELF JOINS and generate_series?

Yep, you're close, but your current query does a Cumulative Average. The tricky part is the *fill the gaps with the previous value* (If PostgreSQL supported the `IGNORE NULLS` option of `LAST_VALUE` this would be easier...)

```
SELECT month,
       year,
       MAX(q_overall) -- assign the value to all rows within the same group
       OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
FROM
 (
    SELECT all_months.month, all_months.year, p.q_overall,
       -- assign a new group number whenever there's a value in q_overall
       SUM(CASE WHEN q_overall IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
       OVER (ORDER BY all_months.month, all_months.year
             ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp
    FROM
     ( -- create all months with min and max date
       SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(date)),
                              date_trunc('month', max(date)),
                              interval '1 month') as date
       FROM fb_parsed 
     ) AS all_months
    LEFT JOIN 
     ( -- do the average per month calculation
       SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM date) as month, 
              EXTRACT(Year FROM date) as year,
              ROUND(AVG(q_overall),1) as q_overall 
       FROM fb_parsed 
       WHERE business_id = 1
       GROUP BY year, month
     ) AS p
     ON EXTRACT(year FROM ym.date) = all_months.month
    AND EXTRACT(month FROM ym.date) = all_months.year
 ) AS dt
```

Edit:

Oops, this was overly complicated, the question asked for a Cumulative Average and then NULLs will not change the result and there's no need to *fill the gaps*

Answer (score 0):

Final query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM ym.date) as month,
       EXTRACT(Year FROM ym.date) as year,
       ROUND(AVG(AVG(q_overall)) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(Year FROM ym.date), EXTRACT(Month FROM ym.date)), 2)
FROM
(SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(date)),
                        date_trunc('month', max(date)),
                        interval '1 month') as date
FROM fb_parsed WHERE business_id = 1 AND site = 'facebook') 
ym LEFT JOIN
     fb_parsed p
     ON EXTRACT(year FROM ym.date) = EXTRACT(year FROM p.date) AND
        EXTRACT(month FROM ym.date) = EXTRACT(month FROM p.date) AND
        p.business_id = 1 AND site = 'facebook'
GROUP BY year, month;
```